# ios delegate not pass value and not enter respondsToSelector in my structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have similar problem. But I don't know why about this structure.

I want to use delegate pass the value about the navigationController pushViewController.

But the structure is Tabs ViewController. The Tabs ViewController is embed the ContainerViewController.

When I click the TabAUIViewcontroller. I want to pass the value use the delegate to ResultViewController.(Yellow UIViewController pass value to Blue UIViewController )

The structure like below:

[image]

In the RootUIViewController.h(green), I add the ResultViewController property.

**RootViewController.h**

```
 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController
 - (IBAction)rootBtnChangePageAction:(id)sender;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)  ResultViewController *resultVC;

 @end
```

The **RootViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.resultVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultViewController"];

   }
```

Then I set the protocol and delegate method in the TabAUIViewController(Yellow).

**TabAUIViewController.h**

```
    @class TabAUIViewController;
 @protocol TabAUIViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

 @optional

 -(void) tabAVC:(TabAUIViewController*)tabAVC passValue:(NSString*) str;

 @end

 @interface TabAUIViewController : UIViewController

 @property (nonatomic,assign) id<TabAUIViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

 - (IBAction)tabABtnAction:(id)sender;

 @end
```

In the TabAUIViewController.m I declare the resultVC and call the parentViewController.parentViewController to pass the value .

**TabAUIViewController.m**

```
 @interface TabAUIViewController()
 {
     ResultViewController  *resultVC;
 }
 @end

 @implementation TabAUIViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     resultVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultViewController"];
 }

 - (IBAction)tabABtnAction:(id)sender {
  RootViewController* tempRootVC = (RootViewController*)self.parentViewController.parentViewController;
    NSLog(@"tabABtnAction");
     if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tabAVC:passValue:)])
     {
         NSLog(@"respondsToSelector");
         [self.delegate tabAVC:self passValue:@"test"];

     }
     [tempRootVC.navigationController pushViewController:resultVC animated:YES];

 }
 @end
```

Then in the **ResultViewController.m** , I had add the delegate.

But I can't get the value in the delegate method.

**ResultViewController.m**

```
 @interface ResultViewController ()<TabAUIViewControllerDelegate>
 {
     TabAUIViewController *tabAVC;
 }
 @end

 @implementation ResultViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     tabAVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabAUIViewController"];
     tabAVC.delegate = self;
 }

 // tab a delegate method
 -(void) tabAVC:(TabAUIViewController *)tabAVC passValue:(NSString *)str
 {
     NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
 }
```

I can't get the value in the ResultViewController.m

I had try to trace the log, there are not enter the

[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tabAVC:passValue:)] method.

How can I use the pushViewController and delegate pass the value in this structure?

Have anyone can resolved the problem using delegate?

Thank you very much.

I had upload the test project and simplify project in [here](https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/tabPassValueUsingDelegate.git).

Comment: You will probably find that the TabAUIViewcontroller that you allocated in `viewDidLoad` isn't the instance that is onscreen.  You need to get the correct instance via the embed segue in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I think your delegate value is null.You must set delegate before calling self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tabAVC:passValue:)

Comment: @Paulw11, I had try to add prepareForSeuge, But there are not enter the method. Because I using the pushViewController.

Comment: @ user, How can I get the delegate in this situation? thank you

Comment: Don't use push view controller - use `performSegueWithIdentifier`.  You can also use an `unwind` segue instead of a delegate